# debian multiple network interface multiple networks

Tags: networking, debian, iptables, gateway

I have a virtual environment with 3 virtual machines on one host. One of my virtual machines has 2 network interface.

I need the virtual machine with two interfaces to connect to two different networks.

HERE is the [topology](http://s2.postimg.org/e7lfe2ddl/setup_network.png) 
[image]

My host host has an

ip 192.168.3.29
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.3.1

The 3 virtual machines have the ip addresses

ip 192.168.3.30
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.3.1

ip 192.168.3.31
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.3.1

ip 192.168.3.32
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.3.1

now i added the following setup to the virtual machine to allow it to communicate to another network.
address 10.10.0.10
netmask 255.255.255.0

I added the line below to the file /etc/iproute2/rt_tables

1 rt2

I then run the following commands.

```
 ip route add 10.10.0.99/32 dev eth1 src 10.10.0.10 table rt2

 ip route add default via 10.10.0.1 dev eth1 table rt2

 ip rule add from 10.10.0.99/32 table rt2

 ip rule add to 10.10.0.99/32 table rt2
```

The ip I am trying to reach is 10.10.0.99 and I want only that one ip to be accessed via this route.

For some reason when i try ping the ip after the above configuration i get destination unreachable.

I can reach the server 10.10.0.99 without the above configuration going through the gateway
192.168.3.1 however there is an unnecessary  number of nodes between my node and the other node which sometimes causes trouble.

Is there something wrong with my steps?

I followed the steps [here](http://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Two_Default_Gateways_on_One_System)

I found another similar question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/120117/multiple-interface-nat-routing)

Which seems to suggest i am heading in the correct direction.

Comment: If you reword your question so as to *not* require extraordinary mental effort to parse, that would probably help.

Comment: I have added an image to assist

Answer (score 1):

If your VM 1  has an IP in the network `10.10.0.0/24` then there's no need for any route to communicate with `10.10.0.99`, since both hosts are in the same network.

You must ensure that the host with IP `10.10.0.99` is in the same switching domain and has a 24 bit subnet mask, i.e. `255.255.255.0`.

If it's not the case please provide more info about the switching config and the IP configuration of host `10.10.0.99`.